# Is there a simple example on how to add an entity extension for customers with field in the admin of shopware 6?

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I want to add an entity extension to a customer in shopware 6. I was able to do so with the examples in the documentation of shopware on the PHP side and now I wonder how to display and modify this new "field" in the shopware 6 backend.

I searched a lot and also tried to find a simple plugin where I could get some inspiration from, but unfortunately I'm not able to find.

So again the question  Is there any simple example on how to add an entity extension for customers with field in the admin of shopware 6? Or an example plugin, where I can see how it could be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're (likely) trying to achieve would be the combination of multiple separate tasks.

1. [If you want to store data in the database you'd need a new custom entity](https://github.com/shopware/swag-docs-custom-entity/blob/master/src/Resources/config/services.xml)
2. [If you want to associate the new entity with the customer you'll need the entity extension](https://github.com/shopware/swag-docs-entity-extension)
3. [You'll need to add a new field in the administration](https://github.com/shopware/swag-docs-administration-new-field)

I've linked to examples respectively, but you'll probably need to take the time and invest in studying the documentation regardless.

I also created an example plugin that combines all these steps and adds a new entity with a height field as association to the customer and displays the field in the administration. You can find the [repository here](https://github.com/dneustadt/DneCustomerHeightExtension).

Comment: Thanks for all the detailed information. This example plugin helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you considered this, but depending on what you are trying to accomplish, the simplest way is probably adding a custom field (this can be done progamatically or even via the admin panel).

The drawback is, that those fields' values are stored as JSON and it has drawbacks when you try to search through them.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. First I used a "custom field". This was very easy to do and worked. At some point, I wanted to filter on that field and then everything is getting more complicated. Also in terms of performance later, I want to have a specific field here :)

Comment: Alright, got it. Then dneustadt's way is the way to go :-)